# Jekyll code block size in header is too small

Tags: css, jekyll, github-pages, rouge

The code block font size is too small on [my website](https://pippim.github.io/2018/05/23/A-timer-to-set-up-different-alarms-simultaneosly.html#) when it appears in Heading 1 lines.

When typing a code block in a header in Stack Exchange we seem to have no problem. For example, when I type the following on this website:

```
# `multi-timer` bash script

The `multi-timer` bash script works in Ubuntu versions 14.04, 16.04 and 18.04. It also works in Windows 10 with Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop installed.
```

The markdown renders properly in HTML as:

## `multi-timer` bash script

The `multi-timer` bash script works in Ubuntu versions 14.04, 16.04 and 18.04. It also works in Windows 10 with Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop installed.

---

Using Jekyll (Cayman Theme) however the font is always a little bit smaller than the normal sized font:

[image: jekyll code block size in header.png]

---

I think the problem is buried somewhere in this [Sass / SCSS code](https://github.com/pages-themes/cayman/blob/master/_sass/jekyll-theme-cayman.scss) on the Jekyll Cayman Theme website:

```css
  code {
    padding: 2px 4px;
    font-family: Consolas, "Liberation Mono", Menlo, Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    color: $code-text-color;
    background-color: $code-bg-color;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
  }
```

Specifically the: `font-size: 0.9rem;` line I believe to be the problem.

***How do I change the code block so it uses H1 font size on an H1 line, H2 font size on an H2 line, etc.?***

If it helps I'm just using Github Pages natively and this is [the repo](https://github.com/pippim/pippim.github.io).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Change `0.9rem` to `92%`

As shown below I've fixed the problem:

[image]

---

### Steps taken

I made the fix by first copying the entire file `https://github.com/pages-themes/cayman/blob/master/_sass/jekyll-theme-cayman.scss` to my repo's `_sass/` subdirectory.

Then I changed `font-size: 0.9rem` line below to `font-size: 92%;`:

```css
  code {
    padding: 2px 4px;
    font-family: Consolas, "Liberation Mono", Menlo, Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 92%;  // Change 0.9rem to 92% for proper size in headings
    color: $code-text-color;
    background-color: $code-bg-color;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
  }
```

### Drawbacks

I don't like the fact if the Cayman Theme repo makes changes to this file I will not gain them as 398 lines of this file are now permanently in my own repo.

That said, I can live with this solution for now. If I improve it I will come back and update this answer.